# php display instragram user feed

Tags: php, json, instagram

I am trying this tutorial with no luck. I tried outputting the count of the json object and it was a count of 1 when it should be 3. object->pagination, object-meta, object->data

I put in a fake access token in the code below. I use my access token from instagram. You can also do this query with your client ID only. I tried that and got the same errors.

When I put these queries in the instagram api console they do return the correct json. Can you guys spot what is wrong?

Here is the tutorial:
http://blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified

Here are the errors:
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in PhpstormProjects\untitled\index on line 41

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PhpstormProjects\untitled\index on line 41

Here is my code:

```
   <?php
   // Supply a user id and an access token
   //$userid = 9999999;
   //$accessToken = "9999999.999999f.cca99999999999";
   //$clientid = "abcdefg999999999999";

   // Gets our data
   function fetchData($url){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
      $result = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $result;
     }

     // Pulls and parses data.
     //$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/9999999/media/recent/?access_token=9999999.999999f.cca99999999999");
     $result = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/9999999/media/recent/?access_token=9999999.999999f.cca99999999999");
     $result = json_decode($result);
     ?>


     <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
         <!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resolution, high_resolution) -->
         <a class="group" rel="group1" href="<?= $post->images->standard_resolution->url ?>"><img src="<?= $post->images->thumbnail->url ?>"></a>
     <?php endforeach ?>
```

Thanks for your time.

I commented out the call to fetchData() and use file_get_contents() and it now works.

Comment: What do you get if you add `var_dump($result);` after `$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/9999999/media/recent/?access_token=9999999.999999f.cca99999999999");` ?

Comment: It just prints out             Boolean false

Comment: That means your HTTP query is wrong. Make sure your credentials are correct. The `$result` should not be `false`.

Comment: I changed the call to fetchData and it works. I am posting my correction up top.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this:

```
 <?php foreach ($result->data as $post): ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php foreach ((array) $result->data as $post): ?>
```

This solution worked for me.:) and warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your connection credentials to the API.

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in PhpstormProjects\untitled\index on line 41` means that there is no array to iterate which means no data returned into `$result`

Comment: Yes, but interestingly enough, if I put the exact json call that is the parameter for fetchData in my browser and download the resulting file it has the proper json.